# headers are not sent correctly, when session_start() is after header(...)

Tags: php, session, http-headers

I've a reduced Example for my question:

Variant header before session_start

```
<?php
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() ) . " GMT");
session_start();
exit;
//Headers Received in the Browser: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

Variant session_start before header (work as expected)

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() ) . " GMT");
exit;
//Headers Received in the Browser: Expires: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 06:42:07 GMT
```

When calling `session_start()` before setting the headers everything works fine and as expected.
But when I'm calling `session_start()` after setting the headers, the headers are not sent to the browser as set in with `header(...)`.

What are the reasons for this? Why is session_start() 'clearing' all of the set headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know about this behaviour, so I looked for the function documentation.
Here are some links that can help you understand what's going on:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

“Note:
This function sends out several HTTP headers depending on the configuration. See session_cache_limiter() to customize these headers.”

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

In fact, depending on configuration of `session_cache_limiter()`, using `session_start()` can overwrite headers "Expires", "Cache-Control" and "Last-Modified".

Hope it helps.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php is a good hint